# Deploy Dashboard application to Kubernetes in vagrantbox (virtualbox)

Tags: kubernetes, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to setup a kubernetes cluster in virtualbox. I followed https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/15/kubernetes-setup-using-ansible-and-vagrant and so far everything seems to work.

But I cannot get the dashboard application to work. I followed the guide from https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard and https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md but I cannot access the Web-UI from my host machine.

My whole setup can be found here: https://github.com/sebastian9486/v-kube-cluster/tree/feature/deploy-dashboard

My Vagrantfile is in src/main/kube-cluster and my ansible playbooks are in src/main/kube-cluster/kubernetes-setup. These parts so far work.

In src/main/kube-cluster/kubernetes-setup/deploy/ is the dashboard.sh to deploy the dashboard application. There may be some more elegant way, but for know I try to just get it running.

Installation looks okay. Output from my dashboard.sh

```
[INFO] Deploy and configure application 'dashboard'
[INFO] Start deployment
namespace/kubernetes-dashboard created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-csrf created
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-key-holder created
configmap/kubernetes-dashboard-settings created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper created
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper created
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
[DONE] Finished deployment
[INFO] Start configuration
serviceaccount/admin-user created
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/admin-user created
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
[INFO] ******************************************************************
[INFO] ***** BEARER TOKEN ***********************************************

eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IlRzWkFqejB1RnJJUjBNUDlXSHo0MEVBZmRlTFN1MmxYRThweFRBVTdRNmsifQ.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.LExiVLOykdGVmtXNyUz2vn0VPc1Gazlng-lKnnBV541XPRjUjudjAaTKvfVoOQfEUDxLTLCLS8ePNPqXpnF3zvf7NEmBV5KCttCQWyqFW5PoiQVF2MbFiIXGMHYfYoBrjw_-BqKtbUAr23akPIp8n0m9OyQrHSbGz4m6T1kt2NwcKAX-rpIvkcLo5SaxFpMb6om-pce2EUjQ8fy17ciskN988_jhTgfXQEuwCuIIoUQ_ZblY1MABtdKE0STt9M78qzkY2sZQv8yeKzpmsWSrpX0CechFlA6Ce1XaWrwbqt6vSYpejuK34j1aWh4cUG-f50LaPwXZUnQhbLRViSZaYQConnection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

[INFO] ******************************************************************
[INFO] ******************************************************************
[DONE] Finished configuration
[INFO] Finished Deployment and configuration of application 'dashboard'
```

But I cannot access the page from my host machine.

List of pods from my master node `kubectl get pods -A`

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system            calico-kube-controllers-86bddfcff-dl6hl      1/1     Running   0          5m49s
kube-system            calico-node-gvjqp                            1/1     Running   0          2m15s
kube-system            calico-node-jsvk6                            1/1     Running   0          5m50s
kube-system            coredns-74ff55c5b-nhkwv                      1/1     Running   0          5m49s
kube-system            coredns-74ff55c5b-pjl97                      1/1     Running   0          5m49s
kube-system            etcd-v-k8s-master                            1/1     Running   0          5m58s
kube-system            kube-apiserver-v-k8s-master                  1/1     Running   0          5m58s
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-v-k8s-master         1/1     Running   0          5m58s
kube-system            kube-proxy-cb79j                             1/1     Running   0          2m15s
kube-system            kube-proxy-vq7lr                             1/1     Running   0          5m50s
kube-system            kube-scheduler-v-k8s-master                  1/1     Running   0          5m58s
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-79c5968bdc-jc7hl   1/1     Running   0          2m11s
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-7448ffc97b-czsdn        1/1     Running   0          2m11s
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the web interface and what error message are you getting ?
Did you try to use `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/` url address ? 
I've used your `dashboard.sh` script and it seems to work fine.

Comment: When I paste the URL from your comment into my browser, I just get "The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." Firefox network tab states "No response data available for this request" ... so it seems the request does not even reach the VM. I tried to access the URL from my host machine, not my master VM.

Comment: Sorry, try this url address: `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`.
Is your host machine the machine from which you ran `dashboard.sh` command ?
Can you check if port `8001` is open on your host machine : `ss -tulpn | grep 8001` ?

Comment: `ss -tupln | grep 8001` gives:
`udp     UNCONN   0        0                                        [::]:48001                     [::]:*`

Your second URL doesn't work either. I still get the response "Unable to connect". I delegated all commands from my dashboard.sh to my master node `vagrant ssh v-k8s-master -c 'the_respective_command'` (see my dashboard.sh)

Comment: So in that case, you can access the dashboard from your master node. If you want to access the dashboard from the host machine, run 
`kubectl proxy &` from your host machine not from the master node.

Comment: any progress ? 
Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: yes your hints work. Thanks a lot ... with vagrant box port forwarding I can access the dashboard application. For latest code see my repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved in the comments section but for better visibility I decided to provide an answer.

After deploying [Kubernetes Dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard), to access it from a local workstation we can create a secure channel to Kubernetes cluster (proxy server between our machine and Kubernetes API server) by running:

```
$ kubectl proxy
 Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

**NOTE:** By default dashboard is only accessible from the machine that started proxy server.

The dashboard endpoint will be accessible under following link:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

To learn about other ways of accessing Kubernetes Dashboard ([kubectl port-forward](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md#kubectl-port-forward), [NodePort](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md#nodeport) and [Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md#ingress)), please visit the [Accessing Dashboard documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md#accessing-dashboard).